# write getc() return value to file as char

Tags: c++, getchar

How do I write the return value from getchar() function to a file?  I tried the following and it wrote integers to the file.  Preferably in a C++ solution?

```
myFile.open("somefile.txt", ios::app);
myfile<<getc(fd);
```

Comment: In C, at any rate, `getchar()` takes no argument — `getc()` takes a file stream argument.  In what way did your code not work?  You've not shown how you open the `myfile` stream (or the `getchar()` stream).

Comment: "did not work" is a poor problem description. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is `myfile`? If it is a `FILE *`, use `fputc` or `putc`.

Comment: Nevermind I think it wrote some numbers to the file.

Comment: "some numbers" being the return value of `getc`

Comment: Although `getc` is not part of standard C or C++, it is a common extension. As with any function, you should begin by [reading the documentation](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/getc). Especially the part that tells you the type of the value that it returns.

Comment: @PeteBecker: C11 [§7.21.7.5 The `getc` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.5).  Are you thinking of the `getch()` function which is not a part of standard C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- no, I was thinking of `getc`, which didn't show up in my web search late last night. But it's there now. Nevertheless, its return type is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem counter-intuitive, but `getc` does not return a `char` - it returns an `int`. This is so that there's an out-of-range value to use to indicate end of file.

The behavior of `<<` is vastly different between a `char` and an `int`. For `char` it puts out the character as you'd expect, but for `int` it outputs the decimal representation of a number.